# Can you identify this game with a mate in 12?

Tags: history, sacrifice, identify-this

I vaguely remember it being from a game played in the USSR ca. 1960.  I'm certain it was from before 1985.

```
[fen "2k1r2r/ppn3pq/b7/5p2/5Qn1/2N1B1P1/1P3PB1/2RR2K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but it's appears to be mate in 12 rather than 10. By the way, are you certain that's the exact position from the game you have in mind?

Comment: Definitely mate in 10.  I had forgotten to place a white bishop on g2, though it doesn't figure in what happens next.

Comment: I'll add the bishop into the diagram. As to the other matter, how do you mate faster than 1.Qxc7+ Kxc7 2.Nb5+ Kb8 3.Rd8+ Rxd8 4.Bf4+ Ka8 5.Nc7+ Kb8 6.Nxa6+ Ka8 7.Nc7+ Kb8 8.Nd5+ Ne5 9.Bxe5+ Rd6 10.Bxd6+ Ka8 11.Nb6+ axb6 12.Ra1# ? (Stockfish thinks it's mate in 12.)

Comment: Right you are - Black can delay.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't find the actual game neither in my database nor at, say, [chessgames.com](http://www.chessgames.com/). However, the position [appears as puzzle 210](https://books.google.com/books?id=_ZekAgAAQBAJ&pg=SL6-PA47&lpg=SL6-PA47&dq=aleksandrov%20zaitsev%201974&source=bl&ots=p3_rNbjwmN&sig=25rzaRIVsENM2oSHR67qdP4I-Vc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aBf1VPCTMIqlNtXNg9gI&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=aleksandrov%20zaitsev%201974&f=false) -- with the apt description "Running around like a squirrel in a cage" -- in the book *1000 Checkmate Combinations* by Victor Henkin, and there it is attributed to a game Aleksandrov-Zaitsev 1974.

Comment: Nicely done, @ETD